# Purpose of doc/main.md in firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

After creating a new addon skeleton there is nothing in `doc/main.md`,
and the addon sdk documentation does not outline specific format of data to save in this file.
What is the purpose of it?
Should it contain specific data related to each `.js` file?
Or completely up to the developer to decide format and/or content?

```
rob@workLaptop:~/test$ cfx init
* lib directory created
* data directory created
* test directory created
* doc directory created
* README.md written
* generated jID automatically: jid1-hDoBEUyOVCBwuw
* package.json written
* test/test-main.js written
* lib/main.js written
* doc/main.md written

Your sample add-on is now ready.
Do "cfx test" to test it and "cfx run" to try it.  Have fun!
rob@workLaptop:~/test$ ls
data  doc  lib  package.json  README.md  test
rob@workLaptop:~/test$ cat doc/main.md 
rob@workLaptop:~/test$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension '.md' refers to Markdown files.

These are usually used to give an overview of what the addon does.

The syntax/format is similar to the one used here on stackoverflow. You can check some reference for how to write it in this [Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

You can also look at some examples of main.md's from addons out there, like [here](https://github.com/lduros/notificationbox/blob/master/doc/main.md) or [here](https://github.com/mozmark/ringleader/blob/master/doc/main.md)